# how to find the instances of each word in the given text using linked lists

Tags: c

So we have a text file with words written on it. We have to print out the frequency of each of them.The comparison is character insensitive meaning that : `tall`  and `TALL` and `tAlL` are considered the same word.

I have already done this exercise using basic for loops and Structures but now i have to implement it using Linked Lists.

My basic idea on how to do this was basically the same as the one i did using the for loops which was: Using a `char buffer[N]` with a predefined N of 100, we scan the file word by word. Then we check if the word already exists in the linked list. If so you break the loop and you dont add the next node and you just increase the frequency else if it was not found you add the new node with frequency equal to 1.

At least thats what i tried to implement.

Heres what i have done so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 100
typedef struct node
{
    char *str;
    int instance;
    struct node* next;

} node;
node *createlist(FILE *file)
{

    node *tmp=NULL;
    node *head=NULL;
    node* p=NULL;
    char buffer[N+3];
    int found=0;

    file=fopen("file","r");
    if(file==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file:");
        exit(1);
    }
    while(fscanf(file,"%s",buffer)!=EOF)
    {
        tmp=malloc(sizeof(node));
        tmp->str=malloc((strlen(buffer)+1)*sizeof(char));
        tmp->next=NULL;
        strcpy(tmp->str,buffer);
        if(tmp==NULL)
        {
            printf("Allocation error");
            exit(1);
        }
        if(tmp->str == NULL)
        {
            printf("Allocation error");
            exit(2);
        }
        if(head == NULL)
        {
            head=tmp;
        }
        else
        {
            p=head;
            while(p->next != NULL)
            {
                if(strcasecmp(p->str,buffer)==0)
                {
                    found=1;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    found=0;
                    p=p->next;

                }
            }
            if(found==1)
            {
                p->instance++;
            }
            else if(found==0)
            {
                p->instance=1;
                p->next=tmp;  // here if found a small error i had 
                              //   made so i moved p->next=tmp  inside 
                              // the else if function 

            }

 

        }
    }

    return head;
}

void printfile(node *head)
{
    node* tmp=head;
    while(tmp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s->%d\n",tmp->str,tmp->instance);
        tmp=tmp->next;
    }
}


int main()
{
    FILE *file;
    node *head=NULL;

    head=createlist(file);
    printfile(head);


    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that it still stores some words that are already used.

For example the text file is

```
Mi illumino di immenso
Illumino di immenso
Di immenso
IMMENSO
```

```
My output is
Mi->1
illumino->2
di->3
immenso->3
immenso->13435072
```

when it should be

```
immenso 4
di 3
illumino 2
Mi 1
```

For now i want to print them.  This one requires them to be printed in the descending order but for now i just want to print them

Any idea on what i might do to fix this?

Comment: Prolly not the source of error, but of course you have to do `if(tmp==NULL)` before `tmp->str=malloc((strlen(buffer)+1)*sizeof(char));` (And a sidenote is that `sizeof char` is always 1

Comment: @klutt ehm not sure i follow but arent you supposed to do the tmp=()malloc(...) then check if tmp==NULL to see if there are allocation errors then you proceed with the inward parts like in this case tmp->str?

Comment: You do your `if (tmp == NULL)` check too late. It should be moved to immediately after the first `malloc`. Likewise, `if (tmp->str == NULL)` should be moved to immediately after the second `malloc`.

Comment: When you have at least one element in the list, you loop and check for a duplicate. But, if `found` is 0, you do _not_ add `tmp` to the tail/head of the list. In either case `tmp` is _leaked_. Since you're comparing against `buffer`, you should only create `tmp` _if_ a duplicate is _not_ found (this prevents the memory leak).

Comment: Note that the correct list is 'backwards', and that you haven't changed `head` in your implementation. You should put a new node at the head of the list: `tmp->next = head; head = tmp;` Simple, with no special case. Also `while(p->next != NULL)` should be `while(p != NULL)`. Again, there is no special case for the first node: it simply isn't in the list.

Comment: @WeatherVane I thought about that actually but for some reason if i do while(p != NULL) instead of while(p->next != NULL) the code doesnt compile at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have simplfied the code a bit, and added error checking. I've also build the linked list in the same direction as required, which makes the job simpler. There is no need to make a special case of `head` at any point. Note that the new node is only made if it did not exist.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
    
#define N 100
typedef struct node
{
    char *str;
    int instance;
    struct node *next;
} node;
    
node *createlist(char *filename)                // pass file name instead
{
    node *head = NULL;
    char buffer[N+3];
    
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "rt");         // no need to have as argument
    if(file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file:\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    while(fscanf(file, "%99s", buffer) == 1)    // but better not to hard code length
    {
        int found = 0;                          // define variables where needed
        node *p = head;
        while(p)                                // not while(p->next)
        {
            //if(strcasecmp(p->str, buffer) == 0) // gcc
            if(stricmp(p->str, buffer) == 0)    // windows                {
                found = 1;
                break;
            }
            p = p->next;
        }
        
        if(found) {
            p->instance++;
        }
        else {
            node *tmp = malloc(sizeof(node));
            if(tmp == NULL) {
                printf("Node malloc error:\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            tmp->str = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
            if(tmp->str == NULL) {
                printf("String malloc error:\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            strcpy(tmp->str, buffer);
            tmp->instance = 1;
            
            tmp->next = head;                   // add to head of list
            head = tmp;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    return head;
}
    
void printfile(node *head)
{
    node* tmp = head;
    while(tmp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s->%d\n", tmp->str, tmp->instance);
        tmp=tmp->next;
    }
}
    
int main(void)
{
    node *head = createlist("test.txt");
    printfile(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
immenso->4
di->3
illumino->2
Mi->1
```

Answer (score 2):

A few issues ...

1. In `main`, you never set `file` to anything, so we have UB (undefined behavior). You probably want to set it from `argv[1]`.
2. `createlist` takes a `FILE *` argument, but then you do `fopen("file","r")` so you're opening a fixed name file.
3. You probably want to change the arg of `createlist` to be `const char *file`
4. Your `if (tmp == NULL)` and `if (tmp->str == NULL)` occur too late.
5. Because you do `while (p->next != NULL)`, you do *not* compare/check against the *last* element of the list.
6. You allocate [and fill] `tmp` *before* deciding if you have a duplicate, so *if* it's a dup, you leak the memory.
7. Better to only allocate `tmp` if it's *not* a dup.
8. At the bottom, you need to do `fclose(file);`

---

Here is your original code annotated with some of the bugs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 100
typedef struct node {
    char *str;
    int instance;
    struct node *next;
} node;

node *
createlist(FILE *file)
{
    node *tmp = NULL;
    node *head = NULL;
    node *p = NULL;
    char buffer[N + 3];
    int found = 0;

    file = fopen("file", "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file:");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (fscanf(file, "%s", buffer) != EOF) {
        tmp = malloc(sizeof(node));
        tmp->str = malloc((strlen(buffer) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        tmp->next = NULL;
        strcpy(tmp->str, buffer);

// NOTE/BUG: this check occurs too late
        if (tmp == NULL) {
            printf("Allocation error");
            exit(1);
        }

// NOTE/BUG: this check occurs too late
        if (tmp->str == NULL) {
            printf("Allocation error");
            exit(2);
        }

        if (head == NULL) {
            head = tmp;
        }
        else {
            p = head;
// NOTE/BUG: this does _not_ compare the _last_ element in the list
            while (p->next != NULL) {
                if (strcasecmp(p->str, buffer) == 0) {
                    found = 1;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    found = 0;
                    p = p->next;

                }
            }

// NOTE/BUG: since we've already allocated tmp, this _leaks_ that memory
            if (found == 1) {
                p->instance++;
            }
            else if (found == 0) {
                p->instance = 1;
                p->next = tmp;          // here if found a small error i had
                // made so i moved p->next=tmp inside
                // the else if function

            }

        }
    }

    return head;
}

void
printfile(node *head)
{
    node *tmp = head;

    while (tmp != NULL) {
        printf("%s->%d\n", tmp->str, tmp->instance);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
}

int
main(void)
{
    FILE *file;
    node *head = NULL;

// NOTE/BUG: file is _never_ defined
    head = createlist(file);
    printfile(head);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 100
typedef struct node {
    char *str;
    int instance;
    struct node *next;
} node;

node *
createlist(const char *file)
{
    node *head = NULL;
    char buffer[N + 3];

    FILE *fin = fopen(file, "r");
    if (fin == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file:");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (fscanf(fin, "%s", buffer) != EOF) {
        int found = 0;

        node *cur;
        node *prev = NULL;

        for (cur = head;  cur != NULL;  prev = cur, cur = cur->next) {
            found = (strcasecmp(cur->str, buffer) == 0);
            if (found)
                break;
        }

        if (found) {
            cur->instance += 1;
            continue;
        }

        node *tmp = malloc(sizeof(*tmp));
        if (tmp == NULL) {
            printf("Allocation error");
            exit(1);
        }

        tmp->str = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
        if (tmp->str == NULL) {
            printf("Allocation error");
            exit(2);
        }

        strcpy(tmp->str,buffer);
        tmp->instance = 1;
        tmp->next = NULL;

        // add to tail of list
        if (prev != NULL)
            prev->next = tmp;

        // start new list
        else
            head = tmp;
    }

    fclose(fin);

    return head;
}

void
printfile(node *head)
{
    node *tmp = head;

    while (tmp != NULL) {
        printf("%s->%d\n", tmp->str, tmp->instance);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    node *head = NULL;

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("No filename specified\n");
        exit(3);
    }

    head = createlist(argv[1]);
    printfile(head);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the program output:

```
Mi->1
illumino->2
di->3
immenso->4
```